# Create list of generics

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have base class for my entities

```
public class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>, new()
{
    public XElement ToXElement()
    {
    }
    public static T FromXElement(XElement x)
    {
    }
}
```

I have to use this strange construction `Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>`, because i want static method FromXElement to be strongly-typed
Also, i have some entities, like that

```
public class Category : Entity<Category>
{
}
public class Collection : Entity<Collection>
{
}
```

How can i create a generic list of my entities, using base class?

```
var list = new List<Entity<?>>();
list.Add(new Category());
list.Add(new Collection());
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you need those disparate types in a collection?

Comment: And classes Category and Collection are generic types of... themselves?

Comment: @DanielPersson it's called the [curiously repeating template pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)

Comment: OK, I see. Thx for straightening that out :)

Comment: you dont need the _Entity<Category>_ constraint if its only purpose is access to _FromXElement_. Just derive from _Entity<T>_ (i.e., _Category : Entity<Category> { }_) and you can call it via _Category.FromXElement(element)_ this will have a strongly typed return value of _Category_

Comment: I need FromXElement/ToXElement in base class and FromXElement should be strongly-typed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't with that definition.  There is no "common base class" between `Category` and `Collection` (other than `object`, of course).

If there *were*, say if `Entity<T>` were defined as:

```
public class Entity
{
}

public class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity<T>, new()
{
    public XElement ToXElement()
    {
    }
    public static T FromXElement(XElement x)
    {
    }
}
```

then you could do

```
var list = new List<Entity>();
list.Add(new Category());
list.Add(new Collection());
```

But what would that buy you?

Comment: I need FromXElement/ToXElement in base class. This doesnt fit

Comment: @Evgraf - then you'll have to cast.  There's not a `FromXElement` method that both `Category` and `Collection` both implement (since they have different return types).

Answer (score 1):

Create a marker interface:

```
public interface IAmAGenericEntity { }

public class Entity<T> where T : IAmAGenericEntity, new()
// ...

public class Category : Entity<T>, IAmAGenericEntity
// ....

var list = new List<IAmAGenericEntity>();
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the lack of an `abstract` marker on `Entity`, I assume that `To`/`FromXElement` use reflection and should work for any subtype of `Entity`. I recommend that you structure your classes as follows:

```
public class Entity
{
    public XElement ToXElement() { ... }

    protected static T FromXElement<T>(XElement x)
        where T : Entity
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Category : Entity
{
    public static Category : FromXElement(XElement x)
    {
        return FromXElement<Category>(x);
    }
}
```

The "boilerplate" is minimal, and it doesn't require that you creatively circumvent the type system. You don't have to worry about the lack of a common base, or about manual conversions. If you like, you can eliminate the boilerplate entirely and just construct your objects directly from `Entity`:

```
public class Entity
{
    public XElement ToXElement() { ... }

    public static T FromXElement<T>(XElement x)
        where T : Entity
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In essence, what you're doing is implementing a type class, which C# does not directly support. There are a number of ways to work around this lack, but I usually find them to be more trouble than they're worth, especially when it comes to static methods. If C# supported static extension methods, it would be simple, but alas it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a non-generic class to be the base class of all entity classes

```cs
public class Entity
{
}
```

and make Entity inherit Entity

```
public class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity<T>, new()
{
}
```

Now you can create the list of entities as:

```
var list = new List<Entity>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding a non-generic version of the class

```
class Entity
{
  // methods

  public T As<T>() 
  { 
    if (this is T) return (T)this;
    throw new InvalidCastException();
  }
}

class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity<T>, new()

class Cathegory : Entity<T> {}
```

and then create the list of the base class:

```
var list = new List<Entity>()
list.Add(new Cathegory());
```

Then, if you want to call a "generic specific" operation, you need to call the "As" function or simply cast the object.